# Prove that the square of an integer a is congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm currently trying to go through Artin's Algebra textbook via a Harvard Extension Course (available on YouTube). I wanted to make sure that my proof was solid for this question.

> Prove that the square of an integer a is congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4

I’ll prove this using induction.

(i) It’s true for a = 1: $ 1^{2} $ = 1. 1%4 = 1. Done.

(ii) Assume it’s true for all n. That is $n^{2} % 4 $ = 1 or 0.

(iii) Prove: If it’s true for n → it’s true for all n+ 1.

That is $(n+1)^{2} $ % 4 = 1 or 0.

Well, $(n+1)^{2}  = n^{2} + 2n + 1. $ 
We know from our inductive hypothesis that $n^{2} $% 4  = 1 or 0. More specifically, if n is odd, then $n^{2} $ is also odd which means $n^{2}$%4 = 1. 
Conversely, if n is even, then $n^{2} $ is even and $n^{2} $ % 4 = 0. Further, 2n + 1 % 4 = 3 or 1. This is because it’s a monotonically increasing set that goes up by 2 at each element.

When n is odd, (2n+1) % 4 = 3, and when it’s even (2n + 1) % 4 = 1. Therefore, using the associativity of the cosets, $ n^{2} $ % 4, when n is odd = 1 + 3 = 0. 
And $n^{2} $ % 4, when n is even, = 0 + 1 = 1.

Thus, in every case $n^{2} $ % 4 = 0 or 1.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This need not necessarily be done using induction.  It is easier to do as simple case-work.  There are four cases to consider: $n\equiv 0, n\equiv 1, n\equiv 2,$ or $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.  In the even cases, $n^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ and in the odd cases $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  Since there are no other cases to consider, these are the only possibilities.

Comment: Isn't that just an instance of induction without specifying it's use? What you're really doing is saying that of course it will continue to be this way for all n as the only possible congruences (mod 4) will be 0...3.

Comment: As far as your proof, you say "*Assume it's true for* **all** $n$..."  This is incorrect wording and should instead be "*Assume it's true for* **some** $n$..."  As for the meat of the proof, everything you did was essentially the case work I suggested instead.  The "induction step" relies on results stronger than the induction hypothesis, making using induction in the first place tedious.

Comment: In response to your comment, it is not really induction.  The fact that every integer falls into exactly one of the four described categories follows immediately from the quotient-remainder theorem.  As such, to prove the statement about all integers, it suffices to prove the statement individually for each part in a partition of the integers separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just$$(2n)^2 = 4n^2$$
$$(2n+1)^2 = 4n^2+4n+1 = 4(n^2+n)+1$$

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution:

- $a\equiv0\pmod4 \implies a^2\equiv0^2\equiv0\pmod4$
- $a\equiv1\pmod4 \implies a^2\equiv1^2\equiv1\pmod4$
- $a\equiv2\pmod4 \implies a^2\equiv2^2\equiv0\pmod4$
- $a\equiv3\pmod4 \implies a^2\equiv3^2\equiv1\pmod4$